# How to find all the column names of a table where the column names match a certain string? (BigQuery)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

How to get a list of all the columns inside a bigquery table which contain a particular keyword?
For eg. Say the table has following columns:

Name | Age | Address | School_Name | School_Address | School_PhoneNo | etc.
I want the names of all the columns which contain the string 'School'. The required result would be:

1. School_Name
2. School_Address
3. School_PhoneNo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run a query like

```
SELECT
 column_name
FROM
 `bigquery-public-data`.census_bureau_usa.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
 column_name like '%age%' and table_name='population_by_zip_2000'
```

This returns:

[image]

Comment: turns out dataset name is case-sensitive. always something new to learn! :)